# meaning of camp down on someone

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What does 'camp down' mean in the sentence: *the army camped down on them with rape and murder?*

Does it connote something like *attack* or *offend?*

Comment: Clamp down, not camp down. Otherwise typo.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

Probably just a typo - should be *The army clamped down on them . . .*

Comment: yeah, it is very likely. i found the sentence in an English hand out by a coaching. also, the meaning is nailed by clamp down.

Answer (score 0):

> [Camp down](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/camp+down) pitch, set up - erect and fasten; "pitch a tent"

I think you're witnessing poetic licence being taken here.  The sentence is meant to evoke the idea that rape and murder are what the army used to set up camp.  Makes a kind of macabre sense.  Kill enough people and the housing market will open up to the point that you don't need a tent.

Comment: i figured something close, but then i had to do the labour of remote imagination. however, i think it can also be a typo, as @Tim mentioned.